# git: branches get merged automatically (and unwantedly)

Tags: git

I finished doing something in a branch and then made the commit and checked out to master and merged that branch with master.

After that, any new branches are automatically merged into master as soon as I create them!

I don't know what I've done wrong, I also searched this and found no same issue, anyone can tell me how I can stop it?

Even when I'm on a branch that is not clean and I want to checkout to another branch it doesn't warn me because it's already been merged! (I've done REALLY nothing strange, it makes me scratch my head!)

Comment: Do you have any hooks? what the script which you are executing

Comment: @CodeWizard I'm not sure what a hook is but according to Google it's a script. No I don't have any scripts except ~/.git-prompt.sh. I'm not executing any other scripts.

Comment: Thanks @CodeWizard, I removed the `~/.git-prompt.sh` and now it's fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the  `~/.git-prompt.sh` and now it's fixed

Comment: And it's weird, since I got that from the official git repository on GitHub. Anyways, thanks.